# Pasting images into gmail from clipboard, shows fine when sent, but arrives as text

Tags: email, images, gmail

I have had consistent problems with pasting images into Gmail. I use Firefox (just in case that is relevant, but I wouldn't expect so). The image displays fine as I write it.  But when it arrives at my family members Gmail account, it is being displayed in some `base64` encoded form as many pages of text with a beginning like:

```
img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA.....
```

On the receiving end I cannot get the images to display properly.

Comment: Are you using Snagit as well?  http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/hpV05eNkKHI

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with Firefox and the compose tool.
If I compose in Chrome,  I can view it in Chrome or Firefox. 
If I compose in Firefox,  it replicates the above symptoms whether I read in Chrome or Firefox.